# Why do C++ compilers have obscure error messages

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Why do C++ compilers (and compilers for other programming languages in general) have rather obscure error messages? Is it perhaps history-based? Laziness? Or is it simply too hard to make clear error messages for everybody?

The error messages produced from template errors can be rather annoying/intimidating. Furthermore, the error messages can use abbreviations that are non-intuitive, such as “static member function cannot have a cv-qualifier.” I believe the “cv” stands for constant/volatile.

Comment: Illustrate — the modern compilers generally produce rather good and explicit error messages.  They assume that you know the language you're writing, but that's all.  As for 'cv-qualifier', that's a technical term of the language used by the C++ standard (§3.9.3 CV-qualifiers [basic.type.qualifier] in the 2011 standard, for example).  Yes, it means 'const or volatile qualifiers'.

Comment: It doesn't matter. While template error generate a wall of text the only important thing is the offending line number of the first error, I never pay attention to whatit says.

Comment: C++ doesn't have error messages. Compiler implementations have error messages. Your question should therefore be addressed to the implememtors in each case.

Comment: Sorry everyone is right about how it's the compiler that produces the error messages, not C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, it's not C++ that's giving you error messages; it is your compiler. This may sound academic but it's an important distinction. Not that it really affects your question, since compiler diagnostics are fairly complex in *all* mainstream implementations.

It's not due to laziness and it's not historical; it's a combination of these factors:

- **a desire to be precise**

  It's no good dumbing down for a few newbies when that means the real professionals don't get information they can use. In your example, "cv-qualifier" is exact and precise and tells you what is going on. You could find some other way of describing it, but that would either not actually map to what's going on in terms of the language you're using, or it would be wrong.
- **implementation complexity**

  Okay, to be fair, template diagnostics can be *dreadful*. There have been efforts to improve this in more recent GCC versions, in Clang, and with tools like STLFilt. But, ultimately, this is hard to get right. It really is just very difficult to do. Feel free to submit a patch to your favourite implementation if you think you can do a better job. :)
- **language complexity**

  C++ is very complex. That is its nature. It is vastly powerful, far more so than a little scripting language or whatever language is giving you prettier messages. One might argue that its construction is *too* complex, and that is a common criticism of the language. It could be said that the *need* for complex, precise diagnostics stems from that at least in part.
- **inability to perform mind reading**

  This is a variation of the first factor. To produce a simpler set of error messages, the compiler would have to know, when your code is broken, what you intended to write instead. That is not possible without mind reading. The compiler can sort of try to guess, but the risk is that it'll get that guess wrong. In fact, in a language as complex as C++, that risk is quite high. So we prefer that the compiler is just straight with us, and we then train our brains to pattern-match diagnostics against the code we've written; a professional C++ developer can usually recognise the cause of a particular error message (triggered by a particular piece of code) within mere seconds … even if that error message happened to be of the sort that, on the surface of it, is completely unhelpful. That's the magic of our trade!

Comment: *Error message simplifiers* do exist, e.g. old [stlfilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html). Ideally compilers should do that, and using their more detailed knowledge of the source code they could name things, e.g. like where-clauses in functional programming. I guess the main reason that's not done is because of limited resources for management and development. For example, g++ outputs associated information for an error message as follow up lines that, as I recall, are suppressed when you ask it to stop on first error, and that's a lack of quality that could have been easily fixed if.

Comment: I understand your points. Being precise is fine, but I just don't like the use of non-intuitive abbreviations in general. Expanding cv-qualifiers to constant/volatile qualifiers achieves approximately the same purpose

Comment: @J-Win: "cv-qualifier" is not only the precisely correct term (taken verbatim from the standard), but it is highly intuitive for C++ developers, because they know what it means. Those who don't need only look it up once. Writing it out in full every time would make the messages less technically correct, _more_ annoyingly verbose, and thus ultimately _less_ useful.